# How to create an array that contains 26 english letters but the order to be set by an input

Tags: java, arrays

I want to know how to create an array that contains 26 english letters but the order of them to be: e.g.

INPUT: problem

and the array would be:

'p','r','o','b','l','e','m','a','c','d','f','g','h','i','j','k','n','q','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'.

I tried to do it but i couldnt

My code is here

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class TabelaEShkronjave {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[][] square = new char[26][26];

    /*char[] fjalaKyqe = {'p','r','o','b','l','e','m','a','c','d','f',
            'g','h','i','j','k','n','q','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
    */

    String word = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write a word: ");
    char[] wordArray = word.toCharArray();
    char[] alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
  }
}
```

Comment: is that your full code? what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @kai , looks like it's - "print letters in inputted word, then remaining alphabet that wasnt in word"

Comment: How is this *trying*?  You don't do anything with `word` after making it into an array.

Comment: @Coffee: How does printing put anything into an array?

Comment: char[] alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray(); 
Will not give the alphabet you want , which appears to be - "the letters of alphabet not included in the word", so try something different.

Comment: @Kai I only showed what I tried to do but didnt know what to do further

Comment: I agree with @ScottHunter you just declare word, wordArray and alphabet but don't do anything to those variables.

Comment: There is more than one way to do this. You should really begin to try something. When you get stuck, ask a new question or edit this one.

Comment: The question i asked is not help me with this code, I asked if anyone knows how to create an array that contains 26 english letters but the order of them to be: e.g.

INPUT: problem

and the array would be:

'p','r','o','b','l','e','m','a','c','d','f','g','h','i','j','k','n','q','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'.

Comment: @MergimRama Your question is clear and it is also clear that you should first put effort into it.

Comment: @YassinHajaj I tried but it didnt work, so i posted half of my code to see if anyone can help me

Comment: Instead of posting half your code, post *all* of your code, along with a description of an errors you get (if any), the input you gave, the output you got, and the output you expected/wanted to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you need to guard against bad input, such as non-letters, repeated letters, and uppercase vs. lowercase letters.

One way to build the desired result is to rely on behavior of `LinkedHashSet`, which will ignore duplicate inserts, so if we first add the letters of the input text, then all letters of alphabet, duplicates will be eliminated for us. The main problem is that the `Set` has to work with boxed `Character` objects, not plain `char` values.

```
private static char[] wordPrefixedAlphabet(String word) {
    Set<Character> letters = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    for (char c : word.toLowerCase().toCharArray())
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
            letters.add(c);
    for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++)
        letters.add(c);
    char[] alphabet = new char[26];
    int i = 0;
    for (char c : letters)
        alphabet[i++] = c;
    return alphabet;
}
```

Another way is to keep track of which letters have already been added, using a `boolean[26]`:

```
private static char[] wordPrefixedAlphabet(String word) {
    boolean[] used = new boolean[26];
    char[] alphabet = new char[26];
    int i = 0;
    for (char c : word.toLowerCase().toCharArray())
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' && ! used[c - 'a']) {
            used[c - 'a'] = true;
            alphabet[i++] = c;
        }
    for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++)
        if (! used[c - 'a'])
            alphabet[i++] = c;
    return alphabet;
}
```

Testing both with the input `"That is NOT a problem!!"` produces:

```
[t, h, a, i, s, n, o, p, r, b, l, e, m, c, d, f, g, j, k, q, u, v, w, x, y, z]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could:

- create an array, the size of the alphabet
- copy into the array the characters of the word
- selectively copy the characters of the alphabet not yet used

Something like this:

```
char[] wordArray = word.toCharArray();
char[] alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
char[] target = new char[alphabet.length];

System.arraycopy(wordArray, 0, target, 0, wordArray.length);

boolean[] used = new boolean[alphabet.length];
for (char c : wordArray.toCharArray()) {
    used[c - 'a'] = true;
}

for (int k = 0, t = wordArray.length; t < target.length; ++k) {
    char c = alphabet.chatAt(k);
    int pos = c - 'a';
    if (!used[pos]) {
        target[t++] = c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Behaves badly for input with non-letters, repeated letters, and/or uppercase letters.

Answer (score 0):

you could do it like this:

```
String word = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write a word: ");
char[] alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();

char[] result = new char[alphabet.length];

int start = 0;
for (; start < word.length(); start++) {
     result[start] = word.toCharArray()[start];
}

for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
     if(word.indexOf(alphabet[i]) == -1) {       
         result[start++] = alphabet[i];
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot Kai, with a little bit of a change this worked

Comment: Behaves badly for input with non-letters, repeated letters, and/or uppercase letters.

Answer (score 0):

Psuedocode:

```
Get the length of the input string
Does the input string contain any duplicate characters?
Tip: Use stringName.charAt(i) and a for loop to test individual characters in string

If it doesn't contain any duplicate characters
    For loop through string length (i)
        For loop through alphabet length (j)
            Find array position of stringName.charAt(i) in the alphabet array (j)
            Swap this array character with current loop position (i). 
            (so 'a' and 'p' in problem swap)
            Break

    For loop through the alphabet array swapped out starting at string length (i)
        if the (int) character is less than the next (int) character in loop
            swap them and set (i) to string length to restart the for loop
Else
    Print an error saying they don't have all unique characters in input
```

While this isn't the most efficient way to do it, it doesn't require any outside classes besides what you're already given, so it is useful if you are a beginner and need more practice in array manipulation and for loops.

Answer (score 0):

After you read the input and got an array of `chars` from the input you can use the following logic to achieve desired result:

```
boolean contains(char[] arr, value) {
    if (arr == null) {
        return false;
    }
    for (char c : arr) {
        if (c == value) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

...

char[] myOrderedAlphabet = new char[26];
int alphabetPosition = 0;
for (char c : wordArray) {

}
for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
    if (!contains(myOrderedAlphabet, c) {
        myOrderedAlphabet[alphabetPosition] = c;
        alphabetPosition++;
    }
}
```

Please note that this snippet does not check if character from wordArray is alphabetic. Hence if you will have characters which are not lowercase latin letters this code will cause an `IndexOutOfRangeException`. You might want to add some additional checks to the code above to prevent errors.